# nothing appears with codeigniter 1.7.2 and 1&1

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I'm trying to upload my website to 1&1 hosting:
I Works with codeigniter 1.7.2 and nothing appears when I run it on the 1&1 host.

I tested my website on  another server and I did not have any problems.

`http://www.mywebsite.com/backoffice/`

this is my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|img|css|js|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: If nothing appears in a PHP site, check your web server's error log for PHP errors. Make sure `error_reporting` is turned up. Alternatively, add to the top of your script `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to enable it at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Is your 1&1 server shared hosting or a VPS? If you're controlling Apache, be sure you have "AllowOverride All" in your httpd.conf otherwise your .htaccess will be ignored.

http://forums.cpanel.net/f5/where-set-allowoverride-all-htacess-222882.html

Comment: The httpd.conf is a server config file. It would make sense that it would work fine locally but not on a different server.